# CSS working on based URL but not in other pages of the site. CodeIgniter

Tags: javascript, php, css, codeigniter, responsive-design

I am creating a simple website. I got a responsive HTML template but the problem is the CSS only works on the based URL but when I started to click the other links the CSS was not applied. I am using CodeIgniter framework. I already tried to change the .htaccess file but with no luck. I am sure that I have used proper declaration of the HTML tags because the CSS showed on the main page (base URL). You can visit the site for your reference

For your reference. Here are the .js and .css included in the template I am using.

```
http://barangayxyz.net23.net/js/skel.min.js
http://barangayxyz.net23.net/js/init.js
http://barangayxyz.net23.net/js/skel-panels.min.js
http://barangayxyz.net23.net/css/skel-noscript.css
http://barangayxyz.net23.net/css/style.css
http://barangayxyz.net23.net/css/style-desktop.css
```

It will be a great help if someone can answer my question.

Comment: Where u add yur CSS js files ?? Header or ?

Comment: @devpro I add it to the header

Comment: Are you sure you load the header on other pages?

Comment: @Jaaaaaaay yes. in fact, just to try it out, I put the content of the header to test the page but it still didn't apply to other pages other than the base url.

Comment: Just want to remind you, the base_url() contains the "/", so it should be something like <?php echo base_url(); ?>page  instead of <?php echo base_url(); ?>/page

Comment: I am aware of that. Thanks. It still doesn't show up. Is there a way i can share with you my codes. Kindly review it?

Comment: can u show your header code, just specific css lines, and also show your controller where u r not getting css files, only index function..

Comment: @devpro thanks for the help. the problem was solved. but the solution was posted in my other post. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using CodeIgniter, place your JS and CSS files outside the application folder. Then fetch your files from these directories

So instead of : http://barangayxyz.net23.net/js/skel.min.js
Write it as : http://barangayxyz.net23.net/your-assets-folder/js/skel.min.js

See directory structure below:

```
root
    - application/
    - system/
    - your-assets-folder/
          - css/
              - your-css-files
          - js/
              - your-js-files
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But it didn't solve my problem.
The problem is the CSS did not applied to other pages. But it did applied to one page alone which is the base url. Even in 




http://barangayxys.net23.net/pages/index

which is the same as the base url, the CSS didn't applied.

could it be the how the css + js were coded? because I just downloaded the template.